# How to make persistent exposed filters in views

Tags: views

I'm aware of the "remember" option of views, but it is stored in session data (not persistent if you logout) and I want to keep the selections saved forever (so the users only have to do the selections once when they sign up).

I've done quite a lot of research regarding different options that maybe could do the trick, but haven't found out yet a viable solution to it. The options I've researched are:

1) With the module "views saved searches" (works but for usability reasons is not an option in this case)

2) Coding a way to remember the exposed filters selected via cookies or database (I haven't found anything about this and I don't know how to code a solution myself).

3) Making the selection in a node or profile page (with CCK, Nodereference/Entity Reference or Relation fields) and applying the selection of each user to "personalize" their view accordingly (maybe following one of the two options briefly mentioned in point 3 of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409382 or using advanced features of relationships and/or arguments)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I reply to myself: The easiest solution is the Views Global Filter module

Comment: is it possible to keep selection when changing language in a multilingual website?

Comment: You should make an answer for yourself, and then answer it so that others know you found an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Views Global Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) module. That will solve your problem.

The project page reads

> Use Views Global Filter on sites that feature multiple Views. You want
>   the views to be driven by the same filter selection, for instance a
>   country, a date range, a search term or even proximity to a post code.